# Spring security excluded path does not call controller's endpoint with Zuul Gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, microservices, netflix-zuul

I would like to disable security for a specific endpoint so that I can make a call to the Controller. Unfortunately, as I perform a call, I get a 304 (I see it in Chrome's developer tools) and I am redirected to the React frontend, ignoring my controller's endpoint

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class MyWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()        
                .and().anonymous()
            .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(new Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint(""), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/ **"))

            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutSuccessUrl(ssoLogoutUrl)

            .and()
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@Import({AuthUserDetailService.class, GatewayWebSecurityConfig.class, VccLoginController.class})
public class GatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(GatewayApplication.class).run(args);
    }
}


@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model) {
        return "login.html";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Notice that I've allowed options request in for every endpoint (since react exploits them before POST and PUT requests) and I've changed the login path regex to `/login/**`.

Comment: Have you removed the second
 `.and()
  .authorizeRequests()
  .anyRequest().authenticated()`
?

Comment: I think I have this issue because I am using Zuul.